# Get inline-block divs to fill the height of the parent

Tags: html, css

I would like two divs to fully extend to the height of the container. Not sure why this is so difficult, but I've tried a few things and can't seem to replicate the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404485/getting-inline-block-elements-height-to-fill-the-parent).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1z9q2sv/2/)

```css
li {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.outer {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: table;
}
.filter-button-name {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
.filter-number-label {
  background-color: pink;
  color: purple;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="filter-item">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="filter-button-name">
        <span>Status</span>
      </div>
      <div class="filter-number-label">
        <span class="label">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider using flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this:

```
.dropdown { height: 100%; }
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c1z9q2sv/3/)

When using percentage heights on elements that are not absolutely positioned, you need to set a height on the parent, as well. See: [*Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B, the linked answer was very informative.